# doctrine 2 - persisting an entity with composite key

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, composite

A Doctrine 2 Entity with a composite key:

```
/**
 * @Entity 
 */
class Test
{
    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column (type="integer", length=11, name="id")
     *
     */
    protected $id = null;

    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column (type="integer", length=11, name="idtwo")
     *
     */
    protected $idtwo = null; 

    public function setIdTwo($id)
    {
        $this->idtwo = $id;
    }

    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

}
```

Saving the Entity

```
$test = new Test();
$test->setId(1);
$test->setIdTwo(1);
$em->persist($test);
```

DB Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `Bella_Test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `idtwo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`idtwo`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Expected result: a row is added to the db table with two id fields, both with a value of 1.

Actual result: No row is added to the db table. No exception is thrown.

Question: What is going on?

Comment: Are you calling `$em->flush()`

Comment: Never liked using composite PKs, sure they work great in theory, but have you ever tried to delete or update one? The app needs to be aware of both values, vs a single PK, where the app only needs to be aware of one id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a try catch block to see what happens

```
try{
    $em->flush(); //don't forget flush after persisting an object
}
catch(Exception $e){
   echo 'Flush Operation Failed: '.$e->getMessage();   
}
```

Other assumption, in my opinion, your entity table name and DB table name may not match each other. I think it's not a bad idea to give a try

```
/**
 * @Entity 
 * @Table(name="Bella_Test")
 */
 .
 .
 .
```